# Remove the URL of closest <a> element from list with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have a list of urls and I have remove button(img button). When clicked to remove button. The url which is next to button must be removed from the list.

```js
let   list   = [];
const remove = document.getElementById('remove')
const view = document.getElementById('view');
const saveInput = document.getElementById('save-input');

saveInput.addEventListener('click', function (){
    list.push(input.value);
    input.value = '';
    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
    render(list);
})

remove.addEventListener('click', function (){
  remove.closest("li").remove();
  render(list);
  })
   
function render(lst) {
  let listItems = '';  
  lst.forEach(element => {
    listItems += `
      <li>
        <a target='_blank' href='${element}'>${element}</a>
        <img src="images/remove.png" 
           onClick="remove_item(this)" 
           id="remove" alt="Remove" width="12" height="12"> 
     </li>`
    });
  view.innerHTML = listItems;
}
```

I am printing the items to screen by using render() function. And my list looks like this.

[image]

Since url is not removed from list by removing closest `<li>` when render() function ran again; item comes back!

So when clicked to bin image; the link next to it must be removed from the list. Thank you!

Comment: what is the `view` element ?

Comment: `view` is the `<ul>` element that `<li>` elements are printed.

Comment: `render` is expecting an argument but you don't pass one in so I'm not sure how your code is working.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 'list` is passed in. I edited the code.

Comment: `list` is empty so what is the code meant to be iterating over to generate that HTML? You should update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: To the `list` , we are adding URLs according to coming data from the user. In the beginning it is an empty array. Then data comes and `list` is not being empty. The issue is that when user decided to remove one of URLs, how to remove it from the `list`. User clicks then `bin` button and the URL must be removed from the `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/er2uj8pL/

Better to remove item from list and render it again (I assumed you are using jquery based on .closest)

```
const remove = document.getElementById('remove')

const lst = ['item1', 'item2'];


remove_item = function(index) {
    lst.splice(index, 1)
  render(document.getElementById('view'));
}
   
function render(view) {
  let listItems = '';  
  lst.forEach((element, index) => {
    listItems += `
      <li>
        <a target='_blank' href='${element}'>${element}</a>
        <img src="images/remove.png" 
           onClick="remove_item(${index})" 
           id="remove" alt="Remove" width="12" height="12"> 
     </li>`
    });
  view.innerHTML = listItems;
}


render(document.getElementById('view'))
```

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you. I changed somethings though for make it proper with my code. Is there a way to pass `index` number with eventListener?

Comment: | And weirdly, this code is not working when it is added as Chrome extension. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate IDs that is not allowed

I would delegate and splice

My code allows you to sort the list

```js
const view = document.getElementById("view");
let list = ["el1", "el2"];
const remove = document.getElementById('remove')

view.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("img.remove")) {
    const removeElement = tgt.dataset.element;
    const idx = list.findIndex(elem => elem === removeElement);
    list.splice(idx, 1)
    render(list);
  }
})

function render(lst) {
  view.innerHTML = lst.map((element, i) => `<li>
        <a target='_blank' href='${element}'>${element}</a>
        <img src="images/remove.png" data-element="${element}"          
           class="remove" alt="Remove" width="12" height="12"> 
     </li>`).join("")
}
render(list)
```

```html
<ul id="view"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

do that this way, with event delegation

```js
/* code for init list ( not accepted in SO snippet)
const
  list = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('list') || '[]')
, view = document.querySelector('ul#view')
  ;
*/
const
  list = ['www.go1.com', 'www.go2.com', 'www.go3.com', 'www.go4.com'] /* just for testing here */
, view = document.querySelector('ul#view')
  ;

// initial render
list.forEach(element =>
  {
  let LI = document.createElement('li');
  LI.innerHTML = `
      <a target='_blank' href='${element}'>${element}</a>
      <img src="images/remove.png" alt="Remove" width="12" height="12"> `
  view.appendChild(LI)
  })

 
view.addEventListener('click', function (event)
  {
  if (!event.target.matches('img[alt="Remove"]')) return

  let 
    LI = event.target.closest('li')
  , iX = list.indexOf (LI.querySelector('a').textContent)
    ;
  list.splice(iX,1)
  view.removeChild(LI)
  // localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list))

  console.log( JSON.stringify(list))  // just for snippet test
  setTimeout(console.clear,3000)     // just for snippet test
  })
```

```html
<ul id="view"></ul>
```

Comment: I was needed to `list` element for the product. The issue was the remove the element from the `list`. Thank you though.

Comment: @Caeculus I updated(v2) my answer, with ths list usage to LocaleStorage

Comment: Do you think this will work when it is added as Chrome extension? Because the answer I marked is not working as extension although it is working ://

Comment: @Caeculus Yes, it also works in a Chrome extension. I don't know of any reason that could refuse this kind of code execution

Answer (score 0):

Your using Id selector `getElementById`
You should use class when there morethen one element with same identity

`const remove = document.getElementByClass('remove')`

```
function render(lst) {
  let listItems = '';  
  lst.forEach(element => {
    listItems += `
      <li>
        <a target='_blank' href='${element}'>${element}</a>
        <img src="images/remove.png" 
           onClick="remove_item(this)" 
           class="remove" alt="Remove" width="12" height="12"> // here change
     </li>`
    });
  view.innerHTML = listItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses event delegation so you don't have to add listeners to all the list items.

```js
let list = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
const src = 'https://dummyimage.com/50x20/efefef/000.png&text=Remove';

const view = document.getElementById('view');

// Attach one listener to the parent list (view)
view.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  if (e.target.matches('.remove')) {

    // Grab the data-id attribute value
    const id = +e.target.dataset.id;

    // If it exists splice out the item from
    // the list and re-render the view
    list.splice(id, 1);
    render(list);

  }

});

function render(list) {

  // Instead of `forEach` use `map`
  const html = list.map((el, i) => {
    return `
      <li>
        <a target='_blank' href='${el}'>${el}</a>
        <img class="remove" data-id="${i}" src="${src}" alt="Remove"> 
     </li>`
  }).join('');
  view.innerHTML = html;
}

render(list);
```

```css
img:hover { cursor: pointer; }
ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<ul id="view"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hi
If you use this method, the list will not change.*

```
const list = ['item1', 'item2'];
let list_items_removed=[];

remove_item = function(index) {
  list_items_reenter code heremoved.push(index);
  render(list);
}
   
function render(view) {
  let listItems = '';  
  lst.forEach((element, index) => {
    if(!list_items_removed.includes(index)){
      listItems += `
        <li>
        <a target='_blank' href='${element}'>${element}</a>
        <img src="images/remove.png" 
        onClick`enter code here`="remove_item(${index})" 
        id="remove" alt="Remove" width="12" height="12"> 
        </li>    
        }
  });
   view.innerHTML = listItems;
}
```