# How can I remove the clicked element and its sibling from list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an extension for save important URLs. And I have a bin icon next to each link for removing the URL. URLs are added manually and stored in an array. You can see the picture below.

[image]

So when bin icon is clicked, the URL next to it will be removed. My HTML code is below:

```
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type..">      
        <div class="button-container">
            <button id="save-input">SAVE INPUT</button>
        </div>
        <ul id="view">
    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My JS code is below:

```
    let list = [];
    const input = document.getElementById('input');
    const saveInput = document.getElementById('save-input');
    const view = document.getElementById('view');
    const localList = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("list") )
    
    if (localList) {
        list = localList;
        render(list);
    }
    saveInput.addEventListener('click', function (){
        if(input.value){
            list.push(input.value);
            input.value = '';
            localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
            render(list);   }
    })
    let remove = document.querySelectorAll(".remove"); 
    Array.from(remove).forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() { 
          let index = el.getAttribute('data-index');
          list.splice(index, 1);
          localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
          render(list);
   })});
    function render(lst) {
          let listItems = '';  
          lst.forEach((element, index) => {
               listItems += `
                    <li>
                        <a href='${element}'>${element}</a>
                        <img src="images/remove.png"  class="remove" data-index="${index}"> 
                    </li>`
        });
    view.innerHTML = listItems;
}
```

The problem with that code is that it is only working when page is refreshed before each removing. How can I solve this?

Comment: [Wasn't this problem already solved for you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69407367/remove-the-url-of-closest-a-element-from-list-with-js)?

Comment: In that problem there is used inline javascript which breaks the Content Security Policy. So it doesn't work sadly :/

Comment: My answer doesn't use inline JS.

Comment: If there is a problem with the 6 other solutions for this same issue you didn't mention it in this version of your question which is a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate a `click` event listener which deletes the entry (by using [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the first parent `li` element) and removes it from `localStorage`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
        e.target.closest('li').remove()
        let index = e.target.getAttribute('data-index');
        list.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
    }
})
```

Jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/j4dc63ro/